# MATLAB function to return part of an array before a zero

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to create a function that receives an array and returns the part of the array before a zero. For instance, `[12, -4, 5, 32, 0, 4, 1, -8]` would return `[12, -4, 5, 32]`, and if the array contains no zero, return the whole array.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function V = Notzero(V)
  V(V==0)=[];
end
```

I an extremely new to MATLAB. I believe what I wrote returns the array without the zeroes, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option, which just clears everything from the first zero to the end of the vector:

```
function V = Notzero(V)
  V(find(V == 0, 1):end) = [];
end
```

For more information, I'd suggest reading up on [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), specifically the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), the [`end`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) keyword, and the [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way (but I like [@gnovice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46285067/2586922) better):

```
result = V(cumprod(V~=0)~=0);
```

Examples:

```
>> V = [12, -4, 5, 32, 0, 4, 1, -8];
>> result = V(cumprod(V~=0)~=0)
result =
    12    -4     5    32

>> V = [20 40 30 10];
>> result = V(cumprod(V~=0)~=0)
result =
    20    40    30    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
V = [12, -4, 5, 32, 0, 4, 1, -8];
idx = find(V==0);
V = V(1:idx-1);
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the requirement _if the array contains no 0, return the whole array._